# Facebook needs to debug three times site to get all the information

Tags: facebook, prerender, google-crawlers

I have an AngularJS site working with PrerendeIO.

That works great, but the issue is that I need to extract three times the information in facebook crawler (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

in order to get the full information.

The first time, facebook get the default values of the site, not the ones coming from the backend.
Then I debug the site, and it brings me the right title and description, but not the image...
The third time, it gets also the image. So after that I'm able to share the url through facebook.

All this happens after the prerender site cached the site. So the issue is not there..

Comment: Facebook is likely fetching the URL too early - before your pre-render service has even done its job. Can f.e. happen when you have a “preview” mode when creating new articles, that uses the final URL already, and on that you have embedded any of the social plugins.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you said about preview mode, can you explain? About the prerender, no, the site was already rendered... I could check that, and I'm debugging the site in Facebook some days after the prerender was made. And that doesn't explain why i always need to do THREE debugs to get the complete information. It always: first one: the defualt content, the second one: title and description, and the third one: the image...

Comment: I am asking whether you have any sort of preview in your CMS, where the person creating a new article can preview it under the final URL already? At a point when it is *not* pre-rendered already (because the author is still previewing, and hasn’t saved it yet.) Or, test it the other way around - right after you published a new article, the debug tool for that same URL should say that this was not scraped yet. If it shows scrape results at that point already, then something triggered it - again, presumably before you actually pre-render the item.

Comment: Feel free to get in touch with us at support@prerender.io. We're happy to help make sure everything is installed correctly and working as expected!